# InteelliJ JavaDoc comment auto update

Tags: synchronization, javadoc, auto-update, intellij-13

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.4 Community Edition. Is there a way to force JavaDoc comment to update when there is new parameter in method?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `JavaDoc Sync Plugin` to install it go to

**File ->Settings -> plugin -> browse Repositories -> search for JavaDoc Sync Plugin and install**

As the doc of **JetBrains** says - *The JavaDoc Sync Plugin will assist you to keep your JavaDoc in sync between interface definitions and the implementations, or method definitions and method overrides. The plugin now uses template based generation of JavaDoc, so that the JavaDoc text can now easily be customized to your needs.*

Comment: I installed the plugin. I don't see any way of activating the functionality.